# How to print results of shell commands that does not have any output

Tags: java, android, shell

I'm running a few shell commands in my android application via `exec` command.

I want to check what was the result of last command, like if any error has occurred or the command has executed successfully.

e.g.

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chmod 755 " + myFile.getAbsolutePath() + "/fileName");
```

Now chmod does not print any result, so how can I check if the permissions has been modified or not.

If I try to print the output of `process` object, like:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

String line = "";
StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    output.append(line + "\n");
}

Log.e("output: ", output.toString());
```

Then debugger never goes inside the while loop & nothing is logged.

Please suggest.

Thank You

Comment: Try using .equals(null) on the String instead of !=

Answer (score 1):

After processing the outputStream, wait for process exit status and compare with 0 (success).

```
int retVal = p.waitFor();
if (retVal != 0){
   Log.e("Error", "process returned exit status: "+retVal);
}
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor%28%29